# button handler in Toast message Ionic 4 is not fired, why?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, toast

I am trying to use Ionic ion-toast.
I found this example in their website: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast

Now my problem is:
"handler" callback for any of the buttons added above is not called and no log appears. I tried this code on Android device and Browser Safari MacOS only both shows same issue.

I tried to use
toast.onDidDismiss().then(()=>{ console.log('Closed'); })
but that does not help since I am planning to add more than one button and I want to distinguish which button is clicked.

- I know I can build my own component to do this but I am trying to know if there is something missing in my code or it is a well-known issue with ion-toast.

Code:

```
  async presentToastWithOptions() {    
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      header: 'Toast header',
      message: 'Click to Close',
      position: 'top',
      buttons: [
        {
          side: 'start',
          icon: 'star',
          text: 'Favorite',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('this log should appear when this icon is clicked.');
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Done',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('This log should appear when I click done.');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    await toast.present();
  }
```

So what I expect:
when I click on the Button 'Done' or the icon 'star' (which are 2 buttons added to the toast) I should see the corresponding console.log in my console but actually I get nothing in the console.

I tried to add break-point also but both of these 2 "handler" callbacks are never called.

No error messages in the console...even no related warnings.

Is this normal? or am I missing something?

Comment: I just put an `await` on `await toast.present();` while tidying up the formatting. I know the docs don't show it but it returns a promise and the docs need updating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just remove `role: 'cancel'` from Done button object and they start working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer will try it, and for the first icon button why it is not called? since there is no role: 'cancel'

Comment: I just set up a test and this answer is correct for me too. The fav click handler is working, and the other one works when I remove the role cancel.

Comment: Thanks for your help. the problem is solved now and thanks for the await correction...btw the formatting issue seems to be caused by stackoverflow editor since it was putting my code in one line until i added a new line after the function prototype then it showed me part of the function outside the code tag but anyway what matters now that the problem is solved. many thanks for both of you

Comment: I still have a small question: the role attribute is it to tag the buttons so we know which button was clicked in case we are using a unified callback ? like "handler: functionName," for mulitple buttons...and function functionName(btn) { ... if(btn.role=='some_role') dosomething(); } ?

Comment: This feels like a bug to me, submitted a ticket for it: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19791

Comment: :) that was easy. Thanks